# hibernate reactive: keep session opened for ontToMany fields

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-reactive

Here my entity:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "GITTBUSUARIS")
public class Usuari {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "USUARIS_ID")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "USUARIS_CODI")
    private String codi;

    @Column(name = "USUARIS_NOM")
    private String nom;

    // @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "id.usuari", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    // private Set<PermisUsuari> permisos;
    
}
```

As you can see, `permisos` field is commented.

Here my repository:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ReactiveJpaSpecificationExecutorBase<T> implements ReactiveJpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {

    private final Mutiny.SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public Mono<T> findOne(Specification<T> spec) {
        CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = this.buildQuery(spec, Sort.unsorted());

        return this.sessionFactory
            .withSession(session -> session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getSingleResultOrNull())
            .convert().with(UniReactorConverters.toMono());
    }

}
```

Above code works right. However, when I uncomment `permisos` field, I'm getting this exception message:

```
Failed to execute statement [select rol0_.ROLS_ID as rols_id1_12_0_, rol0_.ROLS_CODI as rols_cod2_12_0_, rol0_.ROLS_DENOMINACIO as rols_den3_12_0_ from GITTBROLS rol0_ where rol0_.ROLS_ID=@P1]: could not load an entity: [cat.gencat.clt.git.backend.model.persistency.Rol#1]



java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed
```

I'm reaching my code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/qdcf")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Timed
public class QdCFController {

    private final QdCFService qdcfService;
    private final UsuariRepository usuariRepository;

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public Mono<Usuari> user() {
        return this.usuariRepository.findOne(UsuariSpecs.hasCodi("11111111A"));
    }
}
```

How could I keep session opened per thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because the app is trying to load the entity `Rol`.
You are not showing the association with `Rol` in the question but I assume it's a lazy association.

[Hibernate Reactive doesn't load lazy associations on demand like Hibernate ORM](https://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/1.1/reference/html_single/#_fetching_lazy_associations).
If that's the case, you have two options:

- [Load the association eagerly with a fetch join in the criteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria-from-fetch)
- Fetch the roles when you have the result. Assuming the association is called `roles`, it should look something like:

  ```java
  return this.sessionFactory
            .withSession(session -> session
                .createQuery(criteriaQuery).getSingleResultOrNull()
                .onItem().ifNotNull().call( result -> Mutiny.fetch(result.getRoles()) )
            )
            .convert().with(UniReactorConverters.toMono());
  ```

I would need to see the mapping of all the entities involved to help you more